# Converting dates with PHP for DATETIME in SQL

Tags: php, mysqli, sqldatatypes, type-conversion

I have a forum in PHP which takes a date like in the form
`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. However, I need to insert it for SQL as a  DATETIME in the format as `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. How can I convert this data?

Comment: This has been asked here a million times. A quick search will find your answer.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Your date time format is wrong: `dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`. Probably you mean `d/m/Y H:i:s`

If you have 5.3+ version there is safe way to convert the date time into another format. Here's an example:

```
$timestamp = '31/05/2001 12:22:56';
$timestamp = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo $timestamp->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

or if you like more procedural way:

```
$timestamp = '31/05/2001 12:22:56';
$timestamp = date_create_from_format('d/m/Y H:i:s', $timestamp);
echo date_format($timestamp, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Be careful with previous suggestions. Some are completely wrong and others could lead to errors.

Comment: To clarify where you can get a problem. When using strtotime() separator is important; in your case it's slash (/) meaning: US format is ASSUMED (m/d/Y). If separator is dash (-) then european format (d-m-Y) is ASSUMED. So, do not assume anything ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can use the strtotime and date to rework the format.

```
$new_date = date( "Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime( $old_date ) );
```

What this does is take your old date (`dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss`), converts it to a unix timestamp that can then be used with the php date function to format the date to the desired format.

Comment: I can't get this to work it outputs: string(33) "12121212-0505-0909 1212:0505:0000" From $startDatec= date("yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss", strtotime($_POST['startEventDate']));

Comment: Sorry the actual format is `Y-m-d H:i:s` my format was to illustrate what it would return. My Bad. Take a look here on formatting within date function [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) 

So it would be:  `$finalc= date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($_POST['finalDate']));`

Comment: Your suggestion can lead to wrong conversion. Look what I wrote in the comment.

Comment: You are correct, the assumption is that common sense will prevail. Your implementation using php 5.3+ would work perfectly but my solution would work for any version, with the correct considerations in mind.

Comment: I agree to certain extent. Version 5.3+ will replace 5.2+ sooner or later, as in all previous versions. So maybe it's better to think a bit ahead, don't you think?

Comment: Possibly, however there wasn't that scope in the question to presume, so it's best to go for the one-size-fits-all

Comment: This answer is more general than the accepted answer and what I was looking for as most dates you're converting aren't going to have the specific format the accepted answer has.

Answer (score 2):

Two of several possible ways:

1. Convert in code and then pass the converted value to mysql: `$mysqldate = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate );`
2. Let mysql do the work by using its built-in functions:
   `$query = "UPDATE table SET datetimefield = FROM_UNIXTIME($phpdate)  ...";`

Answer (score 1):

if you have datetime avaialable from a from like above format then u just need to use following function.

```
function localToMysql($dateTime){
  $date_chunks = explode('/', $dateTime);
    $time_chunks = explode(' ', $date_chunks[2]);
    $final_format = $time_chunks[0] . "-" . $date_chunks[1] . "-" . $date_chunks[0] . " " . $time_chunks[1];
```

return $final_format;
}